# Normal Equation for linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have the following X and y matrices:

[image]

for which I want to calculate the best value for theta for a linear regression equation using the normal equation approach with:

theta = inv(X^T * X) * X^T * y

the results for theta should be : [188.400,0.3866,-56.128,-92.967,-3.737]

I implement the steps with:

```
X=np.matrix([[1,1,1,1],[2104,1416,1534,852],[5,3,3,2],[1,2,2,1],[45,41,30,36]])
y=np.matrix([460,232,315,178])

XT=np.transpose(X)

XTX=XT.dot(X)

inv=np.linalg.inv(XTX)

inv_XT=inv.dot(XT)

theta=inv_XT.dot(y)

print(theta)
```

But I dont't get the desired results. Instead it throws an error with:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/", line 19, in 
>       theta=inv_XT.dot(y) ValueError: shapes (4,5) and (1,4) not aligned: 5 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd advise against using np.inv as that explicitly computes the inverse of a matrix. This is slower numerically less stable than simply solving the linear system and computing (X'X)^{-1}X' directly. 

To do this, write np.linalg.solve(XTX, X) (after making sure that XTX actually is X'X and not XX' as MaxU mentioned that you computed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using [numpy.linalg.pinv()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html) that is the "pseudo-inverse" instead of numpy.linalg.inv() for the inverting of the matrix since the ducumentation sais:

> "The pseudo-inverse of a matrix A, denoted A^+, is defined as: “the
>   matrix that ‘solves’ [the least-squares problem] Ax = b,” i.e., if
>   \bar{x} is said solution, then A^+ is that matrix such that \bar{x} =
>   A^+b."

and solving the *least-squares problem* is exactly what I want to achieve in the context of linear regression.

Consequently the code is:

```
X=np.matrix([[1,2104,5,1,45],[1,1416,3,2,40],[1,1534,3,2,30],[1,852,2,1,36]])
y=np.matrix([[460],[232],[315],[178]])

XT=X.T
XTX=XT@X

inv=np.linalg.pinv(XTX)

theta=(inv@XT)@y
print(theta)

[[188.40031946]
 [  0.3866255 ]
 [-56.13824955]
 [-92.9672536 ]
 [ -3.73781915]]
```

**Edit:** There is also the possibility of regularization to get rid of the problem of NoN-invertibility by changing the normal-equation to:

theta = (XT@X + **lambda*matrix**)^(-1)@XT@y where **lambda** is a real number and called *regularization parameter* and **matrix** is a (n+1 x n+1) dimensional matrix of the shape:

```
 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 
 0 1 0 0 ... 0 0 
 0 0 1 0 ... 0 0
 0 0 0 1 ... 0 0
 .
 .
 .
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

That is a [eye()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) matrix with the element [0,0] set to 0

More about the concept of regularization can be read [here](http://www.dmi.unict.it/farinella/SMM/Lectures/09Dic2015_2.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have messed up dimensions a little bit. Your `X` is actually a `XT` and `XT` is `X`.

Try this:

```
In [163]: X=np.matrix([[1,1,1,1],[2104,1416,1534,852],[5,3,3,2],[1,2,2,1],[45,41,30,36]]).T

In [164]: y=np.matrix([460,232,315,178])

In [165]: X
Out[165]:
matrix([[   1, 2104,    5,    1,   45],
        [   1, 1416,    3,    2,   41],
        [   1, 1534,    3,    2,   30],
        [   1,  852,    2,    1,   36]])

In [166]: XT = X.T

In [167]: np.linalg.inv(XT @ X) @ XT @ y.T
Out[167]:
matrix([[243.4453125 ],
        [ -0.47787476],
        [268.609375  ],
        [  3.1328125 ],
        [ -5.83056641]])
```

**UPDATE:** this approach gives values that are closer to your desired values:

```
In [197]: (np.linalg.inv(X @ X.T) @ X).T @ y.T
Out[197]:
matrix([[182.27200269],
        [  0.34497234],
        [-38.43393186],
        [-82.90625955],
        [ -3.84484213]])
```

**UPDATE2:** how to create a correct matrix initially:

```
In [217]: np.array([[1, 2104, 5, 1, 45],
     ...:  [1, 1416, 3, 2, 41],
     ...:  [1, 1534, 3, 2, 30],
     ...:  [1, 852, 2, 1, 36]])
     ...:
Out[217]:
array([[   1, 2104,    5,    1,   45],
       [   1, 1416,    3,    2,   41],
       [   1, 1534,    3,    2,   30],
       [   1,  852,    2,    1,   36]])
```

Comment: Can't I set up X directly in the correct shape so that I can to XT=X.T and X is in the correct shape?

Comment: @2Obe, i don't understand... Your `X` matrix that you've created in the question  is the transposed matrix from your picture. The one i see on the picture looks like a correct "not transposed" one. So if you input (create) `X` in a transposed format, you have to transpose it in order to get a correct matrix.

Comment: @2Obe, if you are asking about how to create initially a correct matrix - see UPDATE2

Comment: I have one suggestion: you achieved the desired results by calculating: (np.linalg.inv(X @ X.T) @ X).T @ y.T that is, you transposed the term (np.linalg.inv(X @ X.T) @ X) before "dotting" it with y. But this transposing is not designated in the normal equation. Isn't there a way to achieve the desired result by simpy correctly setting up the matrices X and y and then simply applying: theta = inv(X^T * X) * X^T * y